# Maven build issues - can anyone help me in knowing why I see this error when I do run as maven install

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project resteasy: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.10 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:pom:1.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remotely Closed [id: 0x3004ed34, /192.168.200.22:59080 :> repo.maven.apache.org/93.184.215.223:80] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Looks like a problem with a proxy or with your network connection.

Comment: Did you found any solutions to this? I installed Nexus and keep getting this Remotely closed each time I try do deploy from eclipse with maven. When I look at the repo in nexus, some files get uploaded, really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of options:

1. Use the debugging options. This will produce a lot of output, and probably you'll be able to understand whats really going on.

   mvn -X test
2. In case you're running some kind of proxy on the repository (Nexus, Artifactory, and so on), you can try to disable it in your settings.xml and try to bring the artifact directly from the central repository.
3. Its theoretically possible that something went wrong in your local repository (by default ~/.m2) In this case try to remove all the packages from ''org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.3'' and rerun the build.

How this helps